# CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT GetItem return false for child

Tags: winapi, custom-draw

I am reading tv.pszText of child items in CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT but its returning garbage value every time i ran this code. But it works fine for Parent nodes

```
   LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
    char achBuf[100];
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        LPNMTREEVIEW pnm = (LPNMTREEVIEW)lParam;

        if (pnm->hdr.code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
        {
            LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW lplvcd = (LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;

            switch (lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
            {
                case CDDS_PREPAINT :
                    return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
                    break;
                case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:

                                hwndTree = GetDlgItem(hWnd,ID_TREEVIEW);
                             if(lplvcd->iLevel==0)
                             {
                                    lplvcd->clrText = RGB(0, 255,0);
                                    ZeroMemory(&tv, sizeof(TVITEM));
                                    tv.hItem=(HTREEITEM)lplvcd->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
                                    tv.mask=TVIF_TEXT|TVIF_HANDLE;
                                    tv.cchTextMax=100;
                                    tv.pszText=(LPWSTR)achBuf;
                                    if(TreeView_GetItem(hwndTree,&tv))
                                    {
                                        achBuf;
                                    }

                              }
                            if(lplvcd->iLevel==1)
                            {
                                ZeroMemory(&tv, sizeof(TVITEM));
                                tv.hItem=(HTREEITEM)lplvcd->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
                                tv.mask=TVIF_TEXT|TVIF_HANDLE;
                                tv.cchTextMax=100;
                                tv.pszText=(LPWSTR)achBuf;
                                if(TreeView_GetItem(hwndTree,&tv))
                                    {
                                        achBuf;
                                    }
                               }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
```

Its ruuning fine for level==0 which is parent node but for level==1 which are child nodes its getting garbage value. Help is appreciated!

Comment: We don't know what `achBuf` is. Or why it needs an explicit cast. We also don't know, whether `dwItemSpec` really holds an `HTREEITEM`.

Comment: @IInspectable what do you mean by "dwItemSpec really holds an HTREEITEM" does it contain any other information except tree item ? As i also mentioned above that its working fine for parent node and achbuf is char array already editted the code for you. i am getting really weird characters and signs in achBuf,

Comment: So why is `achBuf` not a `wchar_t` array?

Comment: [`dwItemSpec` does hold the `HTREEITEM`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773470%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @IInspectable what differnce it will make please explain!

Comment: @andlabs Thanks but can you see any problem in above code its not getting level=1 items

Comment: `achbuf` is `char[]`. You're clearly doing a Unicode build since you have had to cast it to `LPWSTR`. So use `wchar_t[]` like you should.

Comment: Yeah you pointed out the correct mistake Thanks!!  i have initalize it to TCHAR achbuff [size] and it works fine